# Check if options are valid to create FAT12 image

Tags: c, validation, file-system

This is a function that checks if a valid FAT12 image would be created. Since all the information to create it is available on the "boot sector", this is the parameter. I wanted the code to be pretty readable, but I may have overdone it.

#### fat.h

```c
/* This file defines some FAT structures, and functions for validating a FAT12
 * objects. */

#ifndef YMFAT12_FAT_H
#define YMFAT12_FAT_H

#include <stdio.h>

/* The names are similar to the specs. */

/* BIOS parameter block (BPB) */
struct fat_bpb {
    unsigned short      bytsPerSec;
    unsigned char       secPerClus;
    unsigned short      rsvdSecCnt;
    unsigned char       numFATs;
    unsigned short      rootEntCnt;
    unsigned short      totSec16;
    unsigned char       media;
    unsigned short      FATSz16;
    unsigned short      secPerTrk;
    unsigned short      numHeads;
    unsigned long       hiddSec;
    unsigned long       totSec32;
};

/* Extended BPB (EBPB) */
struct fat_ebpb {
    unsigned char       drvNum;
    unsigned char       reserved1;
    unsigned char       bootSig;
    unsigned char       volID;
    char                volLab[11];
    char                filSysType[8];
};

struct fat_bootsector {
    unsigned char       jmpBoot[3];
    char                oemName[8];
    struct fat_bpb      bpb;
    struct fat_ebpb     ebpb;
    unsigned char       code[448];
    unsigned char       signature_word[2];
};

/* Returns whether the bootsector information would make a valid FAT12 image.
 * @param       [in]    bs      The bootsector with the sizes of the FAT12
 *                              objects, and volume information.
 * @return                      Whether the FAT12 image would be valid.
 */
bool check_bs(struct fat_bootsector *bs);

#endif /* YMFAT12_FAT_H */
```

#### fat.c

```c
/* Implements what is declared on "fat.h".
 *
 * The "robustness principle" is generally used here:
 *      >> Be conservative in what you send, be liberal in what you accept
 * It is mostly broken when compatibility with MS-DOS would restrict the specs.
 *
 * The specification used was from "August 30 2005" on
 * "https://academy.cba.mit.edu/classes/networking_communications/SD/FAT.pdf"
 * (accessed 2024/01/28)
 * When Wikipedia is mentioned the following article is being mentioned:
 * "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system" (accessed
 * 2024/01/28).
 * When OSDev is mentioned, the following article is being mentioned:
 * https://wiki.osdev.org/FAT (accessed 2024/01/28).
 *
 * Since values besides `char` can vary in length, the value size are checked
 * to be n-bytes long. This does assume 1 byte is 8-bits long, which is wild.
 */

#include "fat.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "error.h"
#include "common.h"

/* For the specs, a FAT is 12, 16 or 32 according to its number of clusters.
 * Different specs define different limits. The used spec defines 4084 for
 * FAT12, as mkfs.dos and Linux driver. The following limit was decided for the
 * following reasons.
 * 1. Cluster _values_ 0 and 1 are reserved, so 4096-2=4094 would be the limit.
 * 2. For Wikipedia, cluster values 0xFF0-0xFF5 are reserved or used, so
 * for portability the limit would be 4094-6=4088.
 * 3. For Wikipedia, cluster value 0xFF6 is reserved. Then the limit would be
 * 4088-1 = 4087.
 * 4. Cluster values 0xFF7-0xFFF have special meaning, so the limit would be
 * 4087-9=4078.
 * Q.E.D.
 */
#define FAT12_MAX_CLUSTERS 4078

static bool overflows3_add_ul(
        unsigned long n1,
        unsigned long n2,
        unsigned long n3
)
{
        if (n1 + n2 < n1)
                return false;
        return n1 + n2 + n3 < n1 + n2;
}

static inline bool overflows_mult_ul(unsigned long n1, unsigned long n2)
{
        return n2 > ULONG_MAX / n1;
}

static inline bool is_16bit(unsigned short n)
{
        return (n & 0xFFFF) == n;
}

static inline bool is_32bit(unsigned long n)
{
        return (n & 0xFFFFFFFF) == n;
}

static inline bool is_lowercase_ascii(char n)
{
        return n >= 0x61 && n <= 0x7A;
}

/* Whether is a valid 8.3 name */
static bool is_83name(const char *n)
{
        const size_t sz = 11;
        size_t i;
        if (n[0] == 0x20)
                return false;
        for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
                if (is_lowercase_ascii(n[i]))
                        return false;
                if (n[i] < 0x20)
                        return false;
                if (    n[i] == 0x22 || n[i] == 0x2A || n[i] == 0x2B
                ||      n[i] == 0x2C || n[i] == 0x2E || n[i] == 0x2F
                ||      n[i] == 0x3A || n[i] == 0x3B || n[i] == 0x3C
                ||      n[i] == 0x3D || n[i] == 0x3E || n[i] == 0x3F
                ||      n[i] == 0x5B || n[i] == 0x5C || n[i] == 0x5D
                ||      n[i] == 0x7C) {
                        return false;
                }
        }
        return true;
}

/* Checks if each field is within specs. */
static bool check_bs_fields(struct fat_bootsector *bs)
{
        /* The function is long, but breaking it would not help, so I added
         * marks for what was being checked. */

        /* jmpBoot */
        /* For OSDev, Windows and OS X do not recognize the volume if the
         * bootjump does not follow the standard. */
        if (bs->jmpBoot[0] == 0xEB) {
                if (bs->jmpBoot[2] != 0x90)
                        return false;
        } else if (bs->jmpBoot[0] != 0xE9)
                return false;

        /* oemName does not need checking. It can be whatever. */

        /* bytsPerSec */
        if (    bs->bpb.bytsPerSec != 512
        &&      bs->bpb.bytsPerSec != 1024
        &&      bs->bpb.bytsPerSec != 2048
        &&      bs->bpb.bytsPerSec != 4096) {
                return false;
        }

        /* secPerClus */
        if (    bs->bpb.secPerClus != 1
        &&      bs->bpb.secPerClus != 2
        &&      bs->bpb.secPerClus != 4
        &&      bs->bpb.secPerClus != 8
        &&      bs->bpb.secPerClus != 16
        &&      bs->bpb.secPerClus != 32
        &&      bs->bpb.secPerClus != 64
        &&      bs->bpb.secPerClus != 128) {
                return false;
        }

        /* rsvdSecCnt */
        if (!is_16bit(bs->bpb.rsvdSecCnt))
                return false;
        if (bs->bpb.rsvdSecCnt == 0)
                return false;

        /* numFATs */
        /* Maybe only 1 and 2 values should be allowed. */
        if (!is_16bit(bs->bpb.numFATs))
                return false;
        if (bs->bpb.numFATs == 0)
                return false;

        /* rootEntCnt */
        if (!is_16bit(bs->bpb.rootEntCnt))
                return false;
        /* Specs does not exclude 0, but it is natural. */
        if (bs->bpb.rootEntCnt == 0)
                return false;
        if ((long)bs->bpb.rootEntCnt * 32 % bs->bpb.bytsPerSec != 0)
                return false;

        /* totSec16 */
        /* If it is 0, then totSec32 is used instead. */
        if (!is_16bit(bs->bpb.totSec16))
                return false;

        /* media */
        /* Wikipedia asserts there is more. */
        if (            bs->bpb.media != 0xF0
                &&      bs->bpb.media != 0xF8
                &&      bs->bpb.media != 0xF9
                &&      bs->bpb.media != 0xFA
                &&      bs->bpb.media != 0xFB
                &&      bs->bpb.media != 0xFC
                &&      bs->bpb.media != 0xFD
                &&      bs->bpb.media != 0xFE
                &&      bs->bpb.media != 0xFF) {
                return false;
        }

        /* FATSz16 */
        if (!is_16bit(bs->bpb.media))
                return false;
        /* Specs does not exclude 0, but it is natural. */
        if (bs->bpb.FATSz16 == 0)
                return false;

        /* secPerTrk */
        if (!is_16bit(bs->bpb.secPerTrk))
                return false;

        /* numHeads */
        if (!is_16bit(bs->bpb.numHeads))
                return false;
        /* Wikipedia says MS-DOS had a bug for CHS with 256 heads up to
         * including 7.1. So most BIOSes do not support more than 255 heads. */
        if (bs->bpb.numHeads >= 256)
                return false;

        /* hiddSec */
        if (!is_16bit(bs->bpb.hiddSec))
                return false;

        /* totSec32 */
        if (!is_32bit(bs->bpb.totSec32))
                return false;
        if (bs->bpb.totSec32 == 0 && bs->bpb.totSec16 == 0)
                return false;

        /* drvNum */
        if (bs->ebpb.drvNum != 0x00 && bs->ebpb.drvNum != 0x80)
                return false;

        /* reserved1 */
        if (bs->ebpb.reserved1 != 0)
                return false;

        /* bootSig */
        /* For Wikipedia, it can also be 0x28, in which case the following
         * fields are not used. */
        if (bs->ebpb.bootSig != 0x29)
                return false;

        /* volID does not need checking. */

        /* volLab */
        /* The specs do not affirm its format, but the examples align with
         * 8.3 names, and that it should be same as the volume file. */
        if (!is_83name(bs->ebpb.volLab))
                return false;

        /* filSysType */
        /* Since it is informational, it could be allowed to be whatever. */
        if (memcmp(bs->ebpb.filSysType, "FAT12   ", 8) != 0)
                return false;

        /* signature_word */
        /* For Wikipedia, MS-DOS <3.3 checked if it was 0x55 0xAA. */
        if (bs->signature_word[0] != 0x55 || bs->signature_word[1] != 0xAA)
                return false;

        return true;
}

bool check_bs(struct fat_bootsector *bs)
{
        unsigned long fatTot, res, fat, rDir, data;
        if (!check_bs_fields(bs))
                return false;

        /* Some ugly overflow checks were needed. */
        fatTot = bs->bpb.totSec16 == 0  ? bs->bpb.totSec32
                                        : bs->bpb.totSec16;
        res = (unsigned long)bs->bpb.rsvdSecCnt * bs->bpb.bytsPerSec;
        fat = (unsigned long)bs->bpb.numFATs * bs->bpb.FATSz16;
        /* On section 4 of the spec, "The size of the FAT is limited to 6K
         * sectors on volumes formatted FAT12". */
        if (fat > 6 * 1028)
                return false;
        if (overflows_mult_ul(fat, bs->bpb.bytsPerSec))
                return false;
        fat *= bs->bpb.bytsPerSec;
        rDir = (unsigned long)bs->bpb.rootEntCnt * 32;
        if (res + fat + rDir > fatTot)
                return false;
        if (overflows3_add_ul(res, fat, rDir))
                return false;
        data = fatTot - (res + fat + rDir);

        if (data > FAT12_MAX_CLUSTERS)
                return false;

        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`fat.h` has no need to `#include <stdio.h>`, so remove that.

However, it does require `<stdbool.h>`.

---

I believe that the on-disk structures have specific sizes, rather than depending on the platform's `char`, `short` and `long`.  If I'm right, we should be using fixed-width types from `<stdint.h>`.  We might also need to take measures to avoid being tripped up by structure padding.

---

Instead of using preprocessor `#define FAT12_MAX_CLUSTERS 4078`, prefer to use an integer constant.

---

I don't like the dependence of `overflows3_add_ul` on unsigned overflow, even though that's well-defined.  It would be more transparent if it tested against `ULONG_MAX` as its multiplicative sister does:

```
    return n2 > ULONG_MAX - n1
        || n3 > ULONG_MAX - n2 - n1;
```

---

The `is_lowercase_ascii()` test might need a comment to say why we're using numeric values for the comparison (i.e. to ensure that the code is still correct when run in a non-ASCII environment) and prevent a future maintainer erroneously "correcting" to `'a'` and `'z'`.

---

I'm not convinced of the correctness of `is_83name()`, having read the description of [directory table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename#Directory_table).  I think it's better to whitelist the *allowed* characters, rather than attempting to enumerate what's not allowed.  And we do we need to handle 0x05/0xE5 in the first position?

---

Testing for exact powers of two might be easier with the common `x & (x-1)` bit-hack, plus a simple range test.

---

`is_16bit(bs->bpb.hiddSec)` truncates the `unsigned long` to `unsigned short` - we need to widen the function's formal arguments, or perform an additional test before truncating with a cast.

---

There's a whole series of tests for non-zero 16-bit values: we might be better off implementing `bool is_in_range(unsigned long value, unsigned long min, unsigned long max)` and using that throughout instead.  A reasonable optimiser knows that `x & 0xffff != x` and `x <= 0xffff` are equivalent.

---

We have redundancy here:

> ```
>     if (!is_16bit(bs->bpb.numHeads))
>             return false;
>     if (bs->bpb.numHeads >= 256)
>             return false;
> ```

The first test can be eliminated.

---

I don't like the cast from unsigned to signed here:

> ```
>     if ((long)bs->bpb.rootEntCnt * 32 % bs->bpb.bytsPerSec != 0)
> ```

`unsigned long` would be a better choice.

---

I don't particularly like the magic-number length here:

> ```
>      if (memcmp(bs->ebpb.filSysType, "FAT12   ", 8) != 0)
> ```

Consider using `sizeof bs->ebpb.filSysType` in place of `8` there for clarity.

Comment: Thank you, Toby! I really liked the idea for a rage function. I used that definition on `is_83name()` because the [specs](https://academy.cba.mit.edu/classes/networking_communications/SD/FAT.pdf#page=24) define that way, but I should prohibit `' '` anyway, since programs did not expect spaces. And I had not thought of that about `is_lowercase_ascii()`, though I have never experienced a non-ASCII environment.